# If I have a date Time Format, is there any to to display only time?

Tags: android, eclipse, date

I have an application that retrieves a string formatted in date time format from a database, and I want to display only the time in certain instances, how would I accomplish this?

This is what I have tried so far but I get an Unparsable error

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";
private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "kk:mm";

// ...

SimpleDateFormat TimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
Date startTimer = null;
Date endTimer = null;

try
{
    String dateString = cursor.getString(6); 
    startTimer = TimeFormat.parse(dateString); 

    //Code for End Time
    String endDateString = cursor.getString(7); 
    endTimer = TimeFormat.parse(endDateString);

    totalBillable += endTimer.getTime() - startTimer.getTime();             
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    Log.e("ReminderEditActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: How do you store your date in the db? in what format?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? If so, what have you found?

Comment: This is what I have tried and have stored so far

Comment: Time Format is "kk:mm", sorry i forgot to mention I need it as a date type so that I can subtract the 2 times.

Comment: I had it working about a month ago and I am not sure what happened, but I have not worked on it since then so I forgot what I did to get it working :(

Comment: Okay, and what are the values of `dateString` and `endDateString` that cause the exception to be thrown?

Comment: Actually thanks to your suggestion I found the problem, the issue was old data that was saved in a different format from the one I am using now, after deleting all of the old data and putting in new data it works fine, thanks for all of the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are getting `Unparsable error` because you are parsing a string date that has different format. Try this:

```
String dateString = cursor.getString(6); 
startTimer = TimeFormat.parse(dateString.substring(11, 16)); 

String endDateString = cursor.getString(7); 
endTimer = TimeFormat.parse(endDateString.substring(11, 16));
```

Hopefully by this `substring()` method, you will get the `kk:mm` date format.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a format which represents what you want, and use that when you only want the time:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String onlyTime = df.format(new Date());
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/AziDU